# how to do time tracking in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, gitlab, watson, issue-tracking

I want to do time tracking in Bluemix and generate CSV reports, based on the ***/spend*** keyword in the issue comments.  There is a program out on Github called *[kriskbx/gitlab-time-tracker](https://github.com/kriskbx/gitlab-time-tracker)* that looks like it will do the trick, but it is designed for generic GitLab, not Bluemix.
I know that the Bluemix issue tracking is based on GitLab, but I can't seem to get the program to work there.  Being unfamiliar with non-bluemix versions of GitLab, I was wondering if anyone has ever been able to get this program to work on Bluemix, or if there is an alternative I can use.

Comment: What kind of issues are you seeing when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. It turns out that kriskbx/gitlab-time-tracker works very well in Bluemix if you configure it properly, especially the Bluemix URL of https://git.ng.bluemix.net/api/v4/, the project namespace/projectname, and a valid security token.  I also had some trouble installing the software on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer using NPM due to some permissions issue, but installing as root seemed to rectify that. I hope this information helps someone else.